# Составить программу, которая вводит с клавиатуры одно целое число

Tags: python

Составить программу, которая вводит с клавиатуры одно целое число a, затем тройку целых чисел b1,b2,b3 и выводит на экран количество чисел в тройке, равных числу a

Answer (score 1):

```
a = input()
b1, b2, b3 = input().split()

print((a == b1) + (a == b2) + (a == b3))
```

либо так:

```
a = input()
print(input().split().count(a))
```